# C# strange behaviour in foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

After a day of troubleshooting I've managed to condense the problem to this tiny piece of code. Could someone explain to me why this doesn't work? I expect [markets] to be 0 2 4 6, [city] [county] and [streets] to be 0 1 2 3 when the messagebox is shown.

```
        private void pieceoftestcode()
        {
            string[] county = new string[4];
            string[] city = new string[4];
            string[] markets = new string[4];
            string[] streets = new string[4];
            string[] items = new string[4] { "apple", "banana", "pineapple", "juice" };
            string[] value = new string[4];
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    if (item == "apple")
                        value[i] = (2 * i).ToString();
                    else
                        value[i] = i.ToString();
                }

                if (item == "apple")
                    markets = value;
                else if (item == "banana")
                    streets = value;
                else if (item == "pineapple")
                    county = value;
                else
                    city = value;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
```

I'm looping through items in a foreach loop. If the item is "apple", then I expect [value] to be 0 2 4 6. Initially [markets] is assigned 0 2 4 6. However, if I execute the code step by step, it appears that the second time that the foreachloop is executed, [markets] is being overwritten. Why is that? What am I doing wrong here? [markets] should not be assigned a value a second time once banana has hit right?

Comment: You only have one array called `value` throughout this, that you keep overwriting and gradually assigning references from other variables to this same array.

Comment: Upvote for posting a [MCVE]

Comment: "However, if I execute the code step by step, it appears that the second time that the foreachloop is executed, [markets] is being overwritten. " This is because `markets = value` sets both references to the same array - and since you're assigning different values to the `values` array, naturally you can see these changes reflect regardless of what reference you're using to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gradually end up with all of your various variables referencing the same array (`value`), with whatever values are written into that array by the last iteration being set.

There's a very similar way of writing this code that avoids the issue:

```
    private void pieceoftestcode()
    {
        string[] county = new string[4];
        string[] city = new string[4];
        string[] markets = new string[4];
        string[] streets = new string[4];
        string[] items = new string[4] { "apple", "banana", "pineapple", "juice" };
        string[] value;
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            if (item == "apple")
                value = markets;
            else if (item == "banana")
                value = streets;
            else if (item == "pineapple")
                value = county;
            else
                value = city;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                if (item == "apple")
                    value[i] = (2 * i).ToString();
                else
                    value[i] = i.ToString();
            }


        }
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

Now, each time through the loop `value` get assigned a reference to a *different* array<sup>1</sup> and so the `for` loop doesn't overwrite its previous efforts.

---

<sup>1</sup>Assuming `items` doesn't contain any duplicate items nor more than one non-apple, -banana or -pineapple item.

Comment: I understand now that we're creating a link between two arrays instead of copying the values inside the array from one array to the other. I do find that a little strange though, but I understand that there might be a memory benefit involved.

Comment: @Maarten - it's not a link between two arrays. You need to get clear the difference between the *variable*, say `markets`, and the array that that variable currently *references*. All we're doing in the assignments is changing *which* array a particular variable is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that in the

```
            if (item == "apple")
                markets = value;
            else if (item == "banana")
                streets = value;
            else if (item == "pineapple")
                county = value;
            else
                city = value;
```

statements you do not create a new array - you just assign the reference to the object. And then you change your array in the for() cycle.

Comment: The solution is to create deep copies of the array or to copy the values.
The main question was "What am i doing wrong here", not looking for the solution